# ¿Como puedo agregar un archivo de javascript en un proyecto de angular 6?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular5

Mi problema es como agregar un archivo de **JavaScript** para usarlo dentro de mi proyecto, ya intente agregarlo a la carpeta `assets` y no funcionna, me aparece lo siguiente:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: editar is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):13)

Mi código es:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="../assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../assets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <title>Intento</title>

  <base href="/">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

El problema es que no se como `instanciar` el archivo de **JavaScript**.

Comment: Hola, edita tu pregunta por favor, no se cargo tu fragmento de código.

Comment: @the-breaker listo, ya esta mi codigo.  :), alguna idea de como importar mi archivo a las dependencias de angular?

Comment: Al parecer no se puede de forma directa, tal vez te sirva ver esta pregunta de Stack Overflow; [How to include external js file in Angular 4 and call function from angular to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j)

Comment: gracias, espero que sea de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me pasó lo mismo. Yo lo metí en el Local State del proyecto. En esa carpeta puedes albergar cualquier tipo de dato para que la aplicación tire de dicha carpeta.
Mi carpeta se situa en esta ruta:

C:\Users\usuarioWindows\AppData\Local\Packages...\LocalState

En la app, te referencias hacia esta carpeta de esta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appdata:///localPackages/.../LocalState/.../fichero.js"></script>
```